# #IBMCloudPrivate X509:certificate signed by unknow authority

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud-private

I still have this issue. I have docker version 17.12.0-ce-mac49 (21995).  I am running IBM Cloud Private on 4 VMs with docker version on Ubuntu 16.  When I run `docker version` on my master node I get the following:

```
Client:
Version:    17.12.0-ce
API version:    1.35
Go version: go1.9.2
Git commit: c97c6d6
Built:  Wed Dec 27 20:11:19 2017
OS/Arch:    linux/amd64

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:  17.12.0-ce
  API version:  1.35 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.2
  Git commit:   c97c6d6
  Built:    Wed Dec 27 20:09:53 2017
  OS/Arch:  linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

On my mac if I run the command:

```
docker login mycluster.icp:8500
```

I login with my user id and password and get the following response:

> Error response from daemon: Get https://mycluster.icp:8500/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

I am trying to load a docker image into IBM Cloud Private and I get the same error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a self-signed certificate on the domain you are mentioning?

Comment: Yes I am.  I used openssl to generate them

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the ICP registry certificate to you host that you want to push image. You can refer below ICP documentation for details.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_2.1.0/manage_images/configuring_docker_cli.html